# Use numpy ndarray object in Apache Hive WHERE condition

Tags: python, numpy, hive, where-clause

I'm using pyhs2 to query Hive from an iPython Notebook. I would like to use. in the WHERE clause on the Hive query. a check within a numpy `ndarray` object.

The query is something like this:

```
q = """
    SELECT *
    FROM luca.pmp_imps iq
    WHERE GUIDBINTOSTR(iq.bidrequestpid) IN {interestingbids}
    """.format(interestingbids = interesting_bids)
results = QueryDataFromHive(q)
```

Now, what `QueryDataFromHive()` simply does is to run the query in Hive and fetch the results in a pandas `DataFrame` object. Nothing more complex than that.
`GuidBinToStr` simply casts variables from binary to strings.

The query in Hive will then be something like:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM luca.pmp_imps iq
    WHERE GUIDBINTOSTR(iq.bidrequestpid) IN ['00009eed-9756-437f-8e83-b0cbb3d375d2'
 '000382d9-f1b2-4d12-b5b9-bb02d34bbb3c'
 '000565a3-f563-40db-b5b5-fe599acfc5ac' ...,
 'fff64455-3b1c-4ae2-bb9b-0f02c02aeccc'
 'fff8f63e-a66c-44b7-b393-0283d969db72'
 'ffffd616-370b-4ec5-8c4a-a9f8cdc53958']
```

I got the following error message:

```
Pyhs2Exception                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-d535411ad0e2> in <module>()
      9 
     10 # print(q)
---> 11 imps_raw = QueryDataFromHive(q)
     12 imps_raw.columns = ['bidrequest', 'userpid', 'mediacost', 'date', 'market']
     13 imps_raw.head()

<ipython-input-21-8db015266821> in QueryDataFromHive(query)
     10             cur.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION guidBinToStr AS 'com.companyname.hive.udf.UDFBinaryToGUID'")
     11             cur.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION guidStrToBin AS 'com.companyname.hive.udf.GenericUDFGUIDToBinary'")
---> 12             cur.execute(query)
     13             df = pd.DataFrame()
     14             for i in cur.fetch():

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/cursor.pyc in execute(self, hql)
     61         self.operationHandle = res.operationHandle
     62         if res.status.errorCode is not None:
---> 63             raise Pyhs2Exception(res.status.errorCode, res.status.errorMessage)
     64 
     65     def fetch(self):

Pyhs2Exception: "Error while processing statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:44 cannot recognize input near 'IN' '[' ''00009eed-9756-437f-8e83-b0cbb3d375d2'' in expression specification\n"
```

Of course this doesn't work because Hive doesn't read properly the object python is sending out. I was wondering if someone has ever encounter such an issue and come out with a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a notation issue.  Instead of using the square brackets `[` and `]` to surround the array you are using for the `WHERE` clause, use parentheses `(` and `)`.  As a rudimentary concrete example:

```
hive> select * from test;
OK
test.field1 test.field2
value1      value2
value3      value4
value5      value6
Time taken: 0.342 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive> select * from test where field1 in ['value1', 'value5'];
...
... [lots of stack trace spam here] ...
...
FAILED: ParseException line 1:35 cannot recognize input near 'in' '[' ''value1'' in expression specification
hive> select * from test where field1 in ('value1', 'value5');
...
... [lots of mapreduce spam here] ...
...
OK
test.field1 test.field2
value1      value2
value5      value6
```

Also, do make sure you're delimiting items in the array with commas if you're not already (I think you are, but it was not completely clear to me from the query excerpt posted in the question).